# Scroll on page with offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using the following script for a smooth scroll effect on my single page website:

```
$('a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

How can i integrate a minus 100px offset into this script? Sorry im a jQuery Newbie... Thanks for your help and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `- 100` to the `scrolltop` value

```
$('a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 100
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by simply subtracting 100 from the offset value ...?

```
scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 100
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code :-

```
scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 100
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/fpxuC/404/

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as you do normal subtraction . Just subtract the `required offset` value . In your case , it is `100px` .Do this :-

```
$('a').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 100
     }, 500);
   return false;
});
```